# Importing a JSON on angularJS with $http.get

Tags: json, angularjs

Im learnign angularJs, and i want to import an array from a json on my controller Like that:

```
myApp.controller("demoCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

            var promise = $http.get("todo.json");

            promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
            });


        });
```

and im using a table to display the data on `todos`:

```
<table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Action</td>
                <td>Done</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in todos">
                <td>{{item.action}}</td>
                <td>{{item.done}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and this results on the flowing html page:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var myApp = angular.module("demo", []);

        myApp.controller("demoCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

            var promise = $http.get("todo.json");

            promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
            });



        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <div class="panel">
        <h1>To Do</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Action</td>
                <td>Done</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in todos">
                <td>{{item.action}}</td>
                <td>{{item.done}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are there errors on the console (browser)? are 'ng-app', 'ng-controller' there in the html body?

Comment: @Mostav I notice that i forgot the ng-app, but I fixed that, and now just show empty <td> tags

Comment: Can you post the whole html and js file if possible? question without all necessary elements will not help at all.

Comment: @Mostav I've edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way of getting access to the json is from the data within the returned object from the http request - you are tying to use the entire returned object.

I use "response" as the return from the get request - then the data is "response.data". This is needed because there are other properties returned within the response object from the get request.

Try changing your promise to be as follows:

```
promise.then(function (response) {
   $scope.todos = response.data;
});
```

Also you should be having a thead and th's and tbody in the table to show a more semantically correct table

```
<table class="table">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th scope="col">Action</th>
       <th scope="col">Done</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in todos">
          <td>{{item.action}}</td>
          <td>{{item.done}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Glad to help - if you can mark the answer as accepted so that other devs know the issues has been resolved. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Promise return entire response in callback Data is in response.data

```
myApp.controller("demoCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
  var promise = $http.get("todo.json");
  // Entire response in callback
  promise.then(function (response) {
    $scope.todos = response.data; // Data is in response.data
  });
});
```

**More:** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http